# importing bootstrap-sass with bower within mean.js application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bower, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://ifrederik.com/blog/2014/06/generating-css-into-mean-js-using-sass/)  , I am not able to resolve the issue that the import of *bootstrap* does not work with the following error:

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../public/lib/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.

SCSS File looks like this:

```
$brand-primary: #967ADC;
$brand-success: #A0D468;
@import "../public/lib/bootstrap-sass official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
.sample { background: $brand-success; }
```

the generated css file contains following error:

> Backtrace: style/style.scss:3
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:66:in
>   `rescue in import' ...

According to the *bootstrap-sass* official ReadMe I do not have to import bootstrap at all, but without the import statement, it does not know the bootstrap variables.

googling has not brought any success unfortunately

Comment: In your code example (but not the error) you have a space between `bootstrap-sass` and `official`, but more important, i thinks so, when installing  `bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save` your scss files are installed in the `bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets`, without `vendor` folder